Pdf downloaded by pupeeteer is saying "We can't open this file"
I am using pupeeteer to download the pdf and send it to front-End,
So the below code is the back-end code using pupeeteer
const downloadResumeAsPdf = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://localhost:4200/resumeBuilder/preview/resume_ooo', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        const selector = '.resume';
        await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 20000 });

        await page.evaluate(async (selector) => {
            const container = document.querySelector(selector);
            const images = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('img'));
            await Promise.all(images.map(img => {
                if (img.complete) return;
                return new Promise(resolve => img.onload = img.onerror = resolve);
            }));
        }, selector);

        const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                top: '20px',
                bottom: '10px'
            },
        });
        console.log('PDF Buffer Size:', pdfBuffer.length);
        console.log('PDF saved as output.pdf');
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="resume.pdf"',
        });

        res.send(pdfBuffer);
        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).send(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`);
    }
};

Below is the services code to call the api
getResumeAsPdf() {
        const options = { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' };
        return this.apiService.post(`${this.targetUrl}/downloadResumeAsPdf`, options);
    }


Below is the front-end code which is called when clicked a button
downloadResume() {
        this.resumeBuilderService.getResumeAsPdf().subscribe(
            (response: Blob) => {
                const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = 'resume.pdf';
                link.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error('Error downloading the resume:', error);
            }
        );
    }

How to fix this issue ? This is my first stack overflow question..
I have tried using pupeeteer but its not working

An easily runnable [mcve] would make it easier to answer this.
